# how to use a toast library with html

Tags: javascript, python, django, toast

I'm using a toast library called js-snackbar with django templates, after a call is being made to the messages, I get Snackbar is not defined on console, am I missing something?

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.tags == 'success'%}
            <script>
                new Snackbar({
                    message: "{{ message }}",
                    status: "success",
                    position: "bl"
                });
            </script>
        {% elif message.tags == 'info' %}
            <script>
                new Snackbar({
                    message: "{{ message }}",
                    status: "info",
                    position: "bl"
                });
            </script>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Where is the external link to js-snackbar library placed?

Comment: @j.ian.le at the top after load static